# What is the simplest way to reference a Multibyte string in PHP?

Tags: php

My question:
In PHP it is easy to reference the single byte string, `$single = "abc";` for example,

```
echo $single[0]; //"a"
```

However for the multibyte string  `$multi = "äåö"`, I get "nonsense", that is,

```
echo $multi[0]; //?
```

I know one can reference the individual letters of a multi byte string by coding as follows:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
echo mb_substr($multi,1,1);//which gives the right answer "å"
```

But isn't there an easier way to do this?
I am especially looking for a way where I can reference the multi byte string  with  square brackets and just one parameter as for the single byte case.

Comment: The array notation version is not multi-byte aware and simply treats the string as an array of single-byte characters. There is no multi-byte aware shortcut notation for substring access.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! 
/William N

Answer (score 2):

No, Unicode support is on the table for new versions, but it is not ready yet. It will get there at some point presumably, but not yet.

[from the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> A string is series of characters, where a character is the same as a byte. This means that PHP only supports a 256-character set, and hence does not offer native Unicode support.

The closest you could get to this is implementing an object implementing `ArrayAccess` using a `__toString()` function and a LOT of fiddling. Not recommended in my opinion.